# page.evaluate() - document is undefined when returning it back to Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I tried to get the Document of a Website with Puppetter but somehow page.evaluate doesnt work the way i thought.

```
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:true});
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
  })
  await page.goto('https://www.tradingview.com/chart/');

  const doc = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document;
  });
  
  console.log(doc)
```

When i print doc it prints undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). As `document` returns a DOM element that is not serializable (it contains methods and circular references), it is replaced with `undefined`. You need to return either serializable value (for example, `document.body.innerText`) or use something like [`page.evaluateHandle()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args) and [`JSHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-jshandle) API.